# Object property is filled when shown but undefined when accessed. Nodejs Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am performing this raw sql query

```
SELECT postId, users.id as userId,users.firstName,users.lastName,users.avatar,COUNT(postId) as 
numOfLikes,body
FROM posts
INNER JOIN likes ON likes.postId = posts.id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.userId
GROUP BY postId
ORDER BY postId DESC
```

through nodeJs sequelize ORM

```
 Posts.findAll({
                attributes: ['id','body','createdAt', [db.fn('count', db.col('likes.postId')), 'numOfLikes']],
                include: [{ attributes: [], model: Likes,required:true, },{model:Users,required:true}],
                group: ['id'],
                order: [['id', 'DESC']]       
            })
```

I receive everything as it should be but cannot access numOfLikes object property (undefined)

```
{
 "id": 18,
  "body": "This show was organized.",
  "createdAt": "2021-03-06T23:55:44.000Z",
  "numOfLikes": 5,
  "user": {
  "id": 73,
  "firstName": "Paolo",
  "lastName": "Jovovic",
  "email": "dzonnna@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": "1",
  "password": "$2b$10$6fLwPfuLP8Jfp7em0iqBm.YhznDut8AWOmUPynqecfd9YMvZBMaXq",
  "google_id": null,
  "avatar": "1_aZF6_EToO4T3ZeHXfgF-Vg.png",
  "role": "0",
  "createdAt": "2021-02-28T22:30:42.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-03-01T23:59:21.000Z"
  }
  }
```

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh i changed id to postId still same issue

Comment: you need add code which show  the undefind

Comment: Any news about this question without using `{ raw: true }` or `.toJSON()`? (They remove some useFull functionality e.g. `.save()` function)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue - I was selecting certain attributes and the query was working correctly.

```
const books = await Book.findAll({
  where: {status_id: [status[0].id, status[1].id]},
  attributes: ["id", "cover", "title", "status_id", "created_at"],
  order: [["_id", "DESC"]],
})
```

the object showed the value but when i tried to access it, it was always undefined.

```
dataValues: {
    id: '9beb341c-a0fa-489d-8a32-c9ec28f0ab16',
    cover: 'cover_500.jpg',
    title: 'birth',
    status_id: '8a5b8c46-b5ac-477a-b1c5-ca2210399e6c',
    created_at: 2022-10-16T02:10:32.000Z
},
```

I should point out here that i've changed the name of createAt in the model

```
createdAt: {
    field: "created_at",
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
},
```

when trying to access the value with `book.create_at` or `book.createAt` both come back as undefined even though they are clearly on the object.  this is a very strange behavior.  since they are in the datavalues they should be accessible.

when I remove the attributes selection column and just return everything for the row, it magically works.

so the issue is either,

1. I changed the name in the model and there is some kind of issue / error in sequalize
2. There is just some kind of issue / error with sequalize access the datavalue

either way, you can grab the whole row and only return / build your object out of the columns you desire.

I switched the attributes to

```
attributes: ["id", "cover", "title", "status_id", "createdAt"],
```

and it is now letting me access the field with `createdAt` but still not `created_at` so the issue appears to be the renaming of the field along with the selection of attributes.

hope this helps someone until they can fix this.

Comment: This help me figure it out I miss  to declare the field on the model, and was just referring the field name in attributes property, thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
        Posts.findAll({
            attributes: ['id', 'body', 'createdAt', [db.fn('count', db.col('likes.postId')), 'numOfLikes']],
            include: [{ attributes: [], model: Likes, required: true, }, { model: Users, required: true }],
            group: ['id'],
            order: [['id', 'DESC']]
        }).then(postList => {
            postList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(postList)) // This is important
            postList.forEach(post => {
                // access post
                console.log(post, post.users)
            });
        })
```